# wordpress jump to page input with search query /page/#/?s=term

Tags: php, wordpress, url, search, pagination

I'm using a pagination plugin that allows users to enter a page number in the input field located below, which allows them to jump to a specified page.

However this is broken when using search pagination, example output of URL when using the input(jump to page) -> /page/2/

Desired behaviour for URL -> /page/2/?s=term

I would like the search query term to be included in the url as well.

Here's the relevant code:

```
    global $wp_query;

    $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

    echo paginate_links( array(
        'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big 
) ) ),
        'format' => '?paged=%#%',
        'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
        'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
    ) ); ?>

    <form class="wpsp-page-nav-form" action="<?php echo  
     $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];?>" method="get">
        <label for="sortby" class="wpsp-label wpsp-hidden"><?php _e('Go to',  
         'wp-smart-pagination'); ?></label>
          <input class="wpsp-input-number" type="text" placeholder="Jump to" 
          size="6" name="paged" />
        <input class="wpsp-button" value="Go" type="submit" > 
    </form>
```

I noticed that the WordPress admin use something almost identical for page navigation:

```
$html_current_page = sprintf( "%s<input class='current-page' id='current-
page-selector' type='text' name='paged' value='%s' size='%d' aria-
describedby='table-paging' /><span class='tablenav-paging-text'>",
        '<label for="current-page-selector" class="screen-reader-text">' . 
 __( 'Current Page' ) . '</label>',
        $current,
        strlen( $total_pages )
    );
```

Resource: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_list_table/pagination/

I have tried incorporating this into my code unsuccessfully..How can I pass the query term with the jump to page input? Any help would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out, passed a hidden input through the form with the search query:

```
<input type="hidden" id="s" name="s" value="<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>" 
/>
```

Not exactly the way I wanted it: ?s=sea&page=2 but good enough.